# Freeswitch command play_and_get_digits transfer on timeout

Tags: python, freeswitch, ivr

I am writing a simple python script in Freeswitch. I need to play a file and detect digits, so I am using the   play_and_get_digits  method of the  session object.

I was wondering if it is possible to transfer the session on dtmf timeout:if the caller does not input any digit, the call should be transferred **without** playing error files or **without** iterating through multiple tries.

So that I could play a file that says: "Hello, press 1 for dev, 2 for sales, hold on line to speak to an agent".

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

see line 136 at https://github.com/xlab1/freeswitch_secretary_bug/blob/master/scripts/inbound_secretary.pl#L136

You set empty error message and 1 millisecond timeout - then you get empty string if the user did not enter anything, or a string with digits if something was entered.